# Connect Android app to external Database (phpmyadmin)

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to connect my android application to an external database.
I have some php scripts on a ftp server that provide some function for my database.
On my phpmyadmin database i have a table 'users'.
when i try to insert a new user my android app access to my php scripts but then the "mysql_query" return always false and the user doesn't appear in my table on the online database.
in my ftp site i have a index.php file and a folder "include". in this folder i have three files with functions and parameters: config.php, db_connect.php, db_function.php.

probably the error is stupid, but i am new to php.
thanks to everyone.

here is my java code:
i use registerUser to insert the user using getjsonfromurl

```
private static String loginURL = "php_script_adress_on_ftp";
    private static String registerURL = "php_script_adress_on_ftp";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        // return json
        return json;
    }
```

//that is the jsonfromurl function

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

here is my index.php file that i call from android app.
$user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password); return always false with error number '1' error in registration

```
<?php

/**
 * File to handle all API requests
 * Accepts GET and POST
 * 
 * Each request will be identified by TAG
 * Response will be JSON data

  /**
 * check for POST request 
 */
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else
 if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registration";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

here is my config.php. is it correct to specify the host in this way? i also tried with http

```
<?php

/**
 * Database config variables
 */
define("DB_HOST", "sql3.freemysqlhosting.net");
define("DB_USER", "my_user");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "my_psw");
define("DB_DATABASE", "mydb_name");
?>
```

here is connect_db.php

```
<?php
class DB_Connect {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // $this->close();
    }

    // Connecting to database
    public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }

    // Closing database connection
    public function close() {
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

here is db_functions.php

```
<?php

class DB_Functions {

    private $db;

    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $this->db = new DB_Connect();
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $result;
            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }



}

?>
```

EDIT: i modified the db_function.php to return also mysql_error but it return nothing

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password,$error) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
        $result = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
        // check for successful store
        if (!$result) {
            // get user details 
            $uid = mysqli_insert_id(); // last inserted id
            $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
            // return user details
$error = mysql_error();            
return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
$error = mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and i modiied the index.php to return the mysql_error
....
....

```
 $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password,$error);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = $error;
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
```

...
...

also i used mysqli_query and not mysql_query but nothing changed.

**SOLUTION:** 
I found out that altervista made a redirect of my HTTP POST and after the redirect it became a HTTP GET without parameters. i don't know what was the reason. i have the domain .com but it redirect the request to .org. so i made the request directly to .org and it starts working!

Comment: `php scripts on a ftp server` I don't think a FTP server can run PHP files

Comment: thank you for the answer!  
are you sure? and where i have to put my php files?
and if ftp server cannot run php files why it return  the "error" string in the index.php file?

Comment: I think you uploaded it with FTP to a web server? On a web server (like Apache) PHP will run.

Comment: Try to output `mysql_error()` at the end of the method `storeUser()`. I don't know where your code fails. Maybe add some outputs, so you can see, which branches will be taken in if clauses etc.

Comment: btw: the mysql_* functions are deprecated. Switch to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Sorry im newby with php.. How can i add outputs if i have not a console? I put "return mysql_error() ;" and not "return false;"?  And get the message in java code as json object?

Comment: `$error = mysql_error(); return false;` doesn't return anything, it just assigns the MySQL error to the unused variable $error. If you replace it with `die(mysql_error());` the MySQL error gets returned to your Java code

Comment: all right i get the error: access denied for user 'my_user_ftp'@'localhost'(using password: NO)
How can i solve it?

Comment: Apparently you aren't connected to the database. Are you sure you user the correct connection settings? The message says you try to connect without providing a password.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that the parameters i pass to my httppost are null on server-side, but are not null when i execute the httppost. so when i access to index.php, the "tag" value is null and the script return me the string in the last "else" clause, that is "Access Denied"
anyone knows why my parameter are null on server side?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I found out that altervista made a redirect of my HTTP POST and after the redirect it became a HTTP GET without parameters. i don't know what was the reason. i have the domain .com but it redirect the request to .org. so i made the request directly to .org and it starts working!